# django uploads via POST to directory but still doesn't see http://localhost:8000/media/picture.jpg

Tags: python, django, nginx

Im trying to configure my static files in django.

I've set

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

and when I upload a photo via admin panel it appears in the folder I want ("src/media") but I cant access it via URL that is

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://web/media/picture.jpg
```

Im not sure if it's not a fault of wrong URL because it's on localhost

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in urls.py were the solution for the problem

Comment: It's ok to do this in development but not recommended for production. Ideally, you'll want to upload to a storage like S3. From there, you can "build" the URL to the uploaded media.